# GRUB not appearing after upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: grub2, windows-8, grub-efi

I had previously dual-booted Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 8. Then I upgraded it to Windows 8.1. Since then my GRUB has not been appearing. I started Ubuntu from my bootable USB drive and ran boot repair. It initially restored the GRUB. I even upgraded it to 14.04. The GRUB appears as long as I keep using Ubuntu. Even if I once start Windows from the GRUB, the GRUB menu does not appear on the next boot. It directly loads Windows.

Here is the link to my boot info summary
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7643346

Comment: are you using easyBCD for dual boot ?? Windows always rewrites the magnetic boot record , how did you made dual boot ??

Comment: i am using easybcd

Comment: what do you mean by that"make dual boot"?

Comment: first of all don't use Easy BCD and by 'made dual boot' I want to convey the primary (first loaded os) and secondary (dual booted os) and if you how did you installed ubuntu by what means (CD or USB flash)?

Comment: Primary OS was windows 8 then I installed ubuntu 13.10 from a usb flash drive. After that I upgraded to windows 8.1. That's when the problem started. After that upgraded to ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Windows 8.1 installer overwritten the GRUB in the MBR with Windows boot loader. Fix is easy, just follow the steps in [Ubuntu Help - recovering Ubuntu after installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) and you will have GRUB with operating system choice again.

Comment: I tried this. The grub appears as long as I use ubuntu. the grub disappears once I choose windows. It appears again only after loading from bootable usb of ubuntu

Comment: Strange. It seems that you have SAVEDEFAULT option enabled wit timeouf set to 0. Do I understand correctly, that you can see GRUB menu as long as keep using Ubuntu only?

Comment: yes it appears as long as I keep using Ubuntu only

Comment: So maybe Windows 8.1 has some mechanism that auto-repair Windows boot loader every run? I am guessing right now...

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: don't use Easy BCD to dual boot it allows every system to change mbr only if you install GRUB directly then MBR will not be overwritten as you see easyBCD works with windows so windows has full access to its mbr while in case of GRUB it has no access to MBR

Answer (score 0):

First reload Windows MBR or boot the Windows OS and uninstall EasyBCD , this will delete it's MBR as EasyBCD MBR is easy to penetrate then, download Ubuntu 14.04 fresh version and make a live USB FLash and reinstall the Ubuntu system this will create a new MBR

I recommend you to create a partition for ubuntu with atleast 100 GB free space and format the old ubuntu partition,then install new fresh copy of ubuntu 14.04 LTS